# How to describe a comparison between three objects?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am comparing three things, but how could I describe the relative order in a single sentence?

For example, is "A is greater than B greater than C" valid?  Or is there a formal way to describe this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you need two clauses for the two different points being made, e.g.:

A is greater than B, which is greater than C.
A is greater than B, and both are greater than C.
etc.

Comment: Neat and logical.

Comment: I like the idea that each comparison needs its own clause but you can avoid the comparisons by using a list. For instance you could say "In descending order the values are A, B and C". The advantage of this is that it can be extended until it becomes unwieldy (probably as far as six or seven values I would say)